# Optimise merge query in oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have approx 400000 rows in source table and approx 100000 rows in target table.
I am using merge query to insert and update the target table.
Target table is also  unique indexed on columns used in on clause of query.
It takes 10 min to execute the query.

Query:

```
merge into target_table tgt 
using source_table src 
on(TGT.tgt_column=SRC.src_column) 
when matched 
then update(...) when not matched then insert(...)
```

Explain plan for query is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | MERGE STATEMENT                |                        |    10 | 94870 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE                         | tgt_table   |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                         |                        |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER          |                        |    10 | 24070 |    33   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL          | src_table     |    10 | 12040 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| tgt_table    |     1 |  1203 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | tgt_index_01 |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   6 - access("TGT"."tgt_column"(+)="SRC"."src_column")
```

It takes 10 min to execute the query.
I need to reduce the execution time to 4-5 mins.

Comment: Based on the query plan, it appears that the statistics on these tables are woefully inaccurate.  Is there a reason they are out of date?  Have you disabled the automatic stats gathering job?  Is the data in these tables transient such that they're mostly empty when the stats job runs?  Did you just populate them with data?

Comment: Yes,I run DBMS_STATS.UNLOCK_TABLE_STATS ();

      DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ();

      DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS ();  before the merge query is executed.

Comment: And also I am just populating with data.Many of the feild are empty also.

Comment: Why are you locking table stats?  Which table(s) are you gathering stats on?  Is there something else in the query you're not mentioning here thatwould make the optimizer believe the `MERGE` is only going to affect 10 rows?

Comment: Hi Justin,I am gatehring stats on target table.There is simple merge query as mentioned above,nothing else.Merge is affecting all the rows as there no where clause.

Comment: So you are not gathering stats on the source table?

Comment: No..source table is truncated and inserted every day.It has no relation with this query.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say that the source table has no relation with this query.  If the optimizer believes the source table is empty (or mostly empty), that would explain why it expects the source table to produce only 10 rows.  That would cause an inefficient join method which would cause the query to run longer than it would if a more efficient join method were chosen.  I would anticipate that with proper statistics on both tables, Oracle would choose a hash join rather than a nested loop join.